If a woman arrives late, should she skip pesukei d’zimra to daven shemoneh esrei b’tzibbur?
There is a well-established practice for men to skip parts of pesukei d’zimrah to finish in time to daven shemoneh esrei with the tzibur. Should a woman also do this?

I don't understand the question. The practice is well established for everyone. No source in your link says anything about men.

According to Rabbi Tzvi Thaler in the name of Rav Kanievsky ztz”l, although the woman is not obligated in the same way in tefilah, she may skip parts of pesukei d’zimrah because the zman tefilah b’tzibur has a special character.
